# SPD Workflow: Adding user to group using REST throws Unauthorized error

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, designer-workflow

I have created a SharePoint 2013 Workflow. This workflow first checks whether a user exists in a sharepoint group for example **My_SP_GROUP** or not by using HTTP GET request. If user does not exists then it adds that user in **My_SP_GROUP** using HTTP POST request.

The problem I am facing is that for POST request I am getting ***unauthorized*** error message, but for GET request it works fine.

> {"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}

From SPO UI, I am able to add user in **MY_SP_Group**. I have followed [this](http://www.connectorman.com/create-sites-with-spd-2013-workflow/) very nice article.

Comment: did you configure workflow for SPO?

Comment: Yes. I have give full control to the Workflow using AppInv.aspx

Comment: @nbi did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Carl not yet :(

Answer (score 2):

When you set permissions for the app step did you set the scope to site collection?
The site groups cannot be edited from a web scope.
Note that there is no web in the scope below

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Thanks to Fabian Williams
http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2014/06/19/gotcha-on-sharepoint-designer-workflows-in-app-step/

Comment: <AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>

Comment: Somehow the closing AppPermissionRequests gets trimmed from the answer :(